# how to create a list of string using groovy

Tags: groovy, gremlin

Suppose I want to collect all bookName as follows:

```
x = g.V.has("books").bookName
```

it shows outpuat as :

```
=>Groovy
=>Java
=>Oracle
```

..

I want to create a list from the above in the following manner :

```
x = ["Groovy","Java","Oracle"]
```

How to create the above list so that I can iterate the list further ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the toList() method, so your query becomes:

```
x = g.V.has("books").bookName.toList()
```

Comment: thanks . yes g.V.has("books").bookName.toList().getClass() returns ArrayList . .:)